# Exception on Update azure mobile services data table

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to develop an app for windows phone using azure mobile services. I am using authentication services provided by azure portal. After authentication the user needs to enter some data like his name, email id etc. Also I have restricted one user to use only one row by using insert script.  I am Taking Input using multiple pages.

myTable

```
public class myTabble
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "age")]
        public int age { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fname")]
        public string fname { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "street")]
        public string street { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "college")]
        public string college { get; set; }
    }
```

my update Function on the Second page button

```
 private async void UpdateCheckedTodoItem(myTabble item)
        {

            await todoTable.UpdateAsync(item);

        }
        private async void myFunction()
        {
            var names = await todoTable
                     .Select(t => t.Id)
                          .ToEnumerableAsync();
            var myName = names.FirstOrDefault();
            string a = myName;


            var item = await todoTable
                .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Id == a)
                .ToCollectionAsync();

            item.street = street.Text; //error
            item.colege = colege.Text; //error



        }

        private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {

                myFunction();

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid input");
            }

        }
```

I am getting this error

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceCollection<Test.myTabble,Test.myTabble>' does not contain a definition for 'hobby' and no extension method 'hobby' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceCollection<Test.myTabble,Test.myTabble>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Comment: Looks like you are creating a new object and trying to update it. You should fetch the object from DB either beforehand or now and then update.

Comment: can you please provide a code sample.

Comment: You update a record that's already in the table, which has an Id already. When you do this: myTabble item= new myTabble();, this has an Id of 0 which indicates it's a new record. So, you should have an Id already when you bring the data to update. Please use that Id to populate the Id property of you new object.

Comment: I have tried my best but did not get the solution. I have updated the question as I tried. please look at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = await todoTable
                .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Id == a)
                .ToCollectionAsync();

var item = items.FirstOrDefault();
if(item != null)
{
    item.street = street.Text; //
    item.colege = colege.Text; //
    await todoTable.UpdateAsync(item);
}
```

I almost forgot the API, I don't remember if there's any call to get one, in that case you don't have to do `ToCollectionAsync()`, which returns a `collection`.